# Get a windows 8 host to access a website hosted in a windows server guest

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am running windows server 2012 as a guest(using Oracle Virtualbox) on a windows 8.

I have a website hosted on the guest OS which i can access in a browser inside the guest.

I would like to be able to access the site as well as other shared files in the guest OS, from my windows 8 host. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the virtualbox home screen:

Settings -> Network -> Adapter1

1. Make sure enable network adapter is checked and attached to NAT.
2. Expand the advanced tab and click on Port Forwarding.
3. Add an entry for http:

   ```
   Name: HTTP
   Protocol: TCP
   Host IP: (Leave Blank)
   Host Port: 3080
   Guest IP: (Leave Blank)
   Guest Port: 80
   ```

Now you can access port 80 listeners on your guest machine, by browsing to the site URL:3080 on your host machine.

Answer (score 0):

Change your network settings for the virtual machine in virtualbox to either 'bridged adapter' or 'host-only adapter'.

Comment: When I do this my Virtual guest can not access the internet

Comment: @Eric It should allow you to access the internet using the bridged adapter setting.